# Delete columns of a nested list with list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

How would I write this for loop as a list comprehention?

This is the list:

```
table = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

I want to delete row 4 and 5

```
for row in table:
    del row[3:]
```

I did try this but it just gives me a syntax error

```
table2 = [del row[5:] for row in table]
```

Any idea how to do that with a list comprehension?

Comment: Welcome, @noskule.   I don't understand the description, starting with "delete row 4 and 5".   I would say that "table" has three rows and five columns.   Did you mean you wanted to delete columns 4 and 5?   What happens if "table" is not rectangular, e.g., [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1]] ?

Comment: A list comprehension is for creating a _new_ list, which is different _behaviour_ from what you have. Why do you think you want to rewrite this?

Comment: Is your intent to delete rows in `table` or to create a new `table2` without the extra rows?

Comment: My intent is to delete rows in table which I dont need so I have no overhead. I get a list of lists like this one:
`[1604448000000, '0.10000000', '0.35000000', '0.10000000', '0.14570000', '3862430.90000000', 1604534399999, '648643.30411400', 4516, '1461260.70000000', '247206.51557700', '0']`

And I need only the first 6 elements:
`[1604448000000, '0.10000000', '0.35000000', '0.10000000', '0.14570000', '3862430.90000000']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice the list upto index 3:

```
>>> table = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
>>> table2 = [i[:3] for i in table]
>>> table2
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

If that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is already the proper way to remove the rows. You could call the list's `__delitem__` method directly, but you are merely using the comprehension for its side effects which is considered "unpythonic". Its done by using a `slice` object:

```
table2 = [row.__delitem__(slice(3)) for row in table]
```

but `table2` ends up as the quite boring

```
[None, None, None]
```

That's one of the reasons why we don't use list comprehensions this way. Besides being non-obvious, we create useless objects. But if its got the cool factor for you, go for it.